# RxJava2: onComplete not called with flatMapIterable

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

Here is short snippet of code:

```
    val subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(emptyList<Int>())
    subject.onNext(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
    subject.flatMapIterable { list: List<Int> -> list }
            .subscribeBy(
                    onNext = { l("on next", it) },
                    onComplete = { l("on complete") }
            )
```

Why `onComplete` doesn't not call here? What I should do for working this code? Because in original code I can not use `.toList()` method.

Comment: Why are you using a `BehaviorSubject`? You have to call `onComplete()` on it explicitly.

Comment: Why would `onComplete` be called here? Your subject isn't done emitting items yet - you could still call `onNext` on it with items.

Comment: @zsmb13 So calling of onCompete is same as in subject? I thought it will redefined by observable in flatMapIterable.

Comment: `flatMapIterable` will only emit events based on the ones that it itself receives. In the case of `onComplete`, it will complete right when whatever it's chained to completes.

Comment: @zsmb13 thanks for the answer. I tried call `onComplete` method on subject, but `onNext` was not called, only `onComplete` of subscriber. How I can work it as I expeceted, i.e. flatMap iterable with calling `onNext` and `onComplete` of subscriber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BehaviorSubject` you have in its form is an infinite source unless `onComplete` is called on it. Therefore `flatMapIterable` will not complete and your `onComplete` handler will never get invoked.

So either you complete the `BehaviorSubject`:

```
val subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(emptyList<Int>())
subject.onNext(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
subject.flatMapIterable { list: List<Int> -> list }
       .subscribeBy(
                onNext = { l("on next", it) },
                onComplete = { l("on complete") }
       )

subject.onComplete() // <-----------------------------------------------------
```

or you take at most one item of it

```
val subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(emptyList<Int>())
subject.onNext(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
subject.take(1) // <----------------------------------------------------------
       .flatMapIterable { list: List<Int> -> list }
       .subscribeBy(
                onNext = { l("on next", it) },
                onComplete = { l("on complete") }
       )
```

Comment: @akarnold thanks for the answer, but when I complete `BehaviorSubject`, new subscribers will not receive `onNext` event, as I expected.

Comment: Use `ReplaySubject` or `AsyncSubject` in that case.

Comment: @akarnold thank you. AsyncSubject works as I expected!